# How to write the summation for Taylor series where first term has no $x$ value

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I am asked to find the power series expansion for $f(x)$
on the interval(-1,1)
$$f(x)=\frac{-(x+1)}{(x-1)^3}$$

I get $1+4x+9x^2+16x^3$

so

$$ \sum_{k=2}^\infty\ k^2x^{k-1}$$

My question is how to write the summation for $$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty\ $$ 
I'm not sure how to write the summation to include the first term since the first term has no $x$.

Also I am asked to evaluate the power series at $1/2$ in $(-1,1)$ Does that mean just set the c value which was $0$ in the Maclaurin series and find the Taylor series for $1/2$?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}k^2x^{k-1}\equiv \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)^2x^{k}$$

I think you are correct about the second thing. Perhaps they mean power series about $x=0.5$ which then means you apply the Taylor Formula about $x=0.5.$

Comment: The second sum should start at $k=1$, not $k=0$

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Harry Alli got it right since when $k=0$ we have $(0+1)^{2}x^0=1$ and $k=1$ we have $(1+1)^2x^1=4x$, so why would the summation start at $k=1$ not $k=0$?@saulspatz