# How to write an infinite sum for $f(x)=\frac{-(x+1)}{(x-1)^3}$

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I am asked to evaluate the power series at $1/2$ in $(-1,1)$ for $$f(x)=\frac{-(x+1)}{(x-1)^3}$$
I get 
$${\frac{-x−1}{(x−1)^3}}≈12+80(x−{\frac{1}{2}})+336(x−{\frac{1}{2}})^{2}+1152(x−{\frac{1}{2}})^{3}+3520(x−{\frac{1}{2}})^4$$

My question is assuming I've done my calculations properly, how do I write this as an infinite sum?

Also when asked to evaluate a power series should I find the interval of convergence or just find the sum?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Generally, the trick is to find a pattern for the $f^{(n)}(\frac{1}{2})$ term. You have evaluated this term for the first 5 terms ($n=0,1,2,3,4$), but what does that term look like when we leave $n$ as a variable?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2706730/how-to-write-the-summation-for-taylor-series-where-first-term-has-no-x-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^3} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)^2 x^n.
\end{eqnarray*}
So 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^3} \mid_{x=\frac{1}{2}}=\color{red}{12} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)^2 \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^n.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I don't understand the second line could you please clarify?@DonaldSplutterwit

Comment: To evaluate the series at $x=1/2$, just plug the value $x=1/2$ into the function.